# How to get test coverage of return values after calling a flow?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, visual-workflow

Apparently, Salesforce test class apex looses control once a flow has been initiated.

Trying to get 100% cover, I have a method that returns a value.

Can't figure how to add that in to the test method.

- Do I use Assertequals()?

[image]

**Code**

```
public without sharing class LaunchPaymentRequest {

    //Instance of the Flow
    public Flow.Interview.Create_Order myFlow {get; set;}
    public String varOpportunityId {get; set;} 

    // http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/

    public LaunchPaymentRequest(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {}

    //https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095o9IAA
    public string startFlow() {
        string varOpportunityId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('varOpportunityId'); 

        Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
        myMap.put('varOpportunityId', varOpportunityId);
        myFlow = new Flow.Interview.Create_Order(myMap);
        myFlow.start(); 

        // Obtain the results
        String returnValue = (String) myFlow.getVariableValue('ReturnPaymentLink');
        System.debug('Flow returned ' + returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }
```

**Test Code**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class LaunchPaymentRequestTest {

    public static testMethod void testLaucnhPaymentStart(){
        PageReference pageRef = Page.success;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 

        LaunchPaymentRequest LaunchPaymentRequestController = new LaunchPaymentRequest(null);

        LaunchPaymentRequestController.varOpportunityId ='0068E000004vtmH'; // YO SFSE'ers I know, just ignore the hardcoded ID :-)

        String startnextPage = LaunchPaymentRequestController.confirmPayOppty();
        system.debug('startnextPage: ' + startnextPage);

        System.assertEquals('/apex/decline', LaunchPaymentRequestController.startFlow());
    }
```

The flow is Autolaunched flow, getting one parameter as input: **varOpportunityId**

[image]

- As for the on hold status: I think this is indeed a general problem, as the issue is not how to test for a value, but if it's at all possible today.
- P.S. I am not following SSCCE since I am not looking for a code issue here. The problem is a general one, not specific to my code.

Comment: Saariko - the issue at hand is how does SFDC provide mock results for the result of the visual flow - I don't think there is a solution here

Comment: @cropredy apparently you are right. This is not available today. Post as answer to accept

Comment: Can we see your test code (are you using test.stoptest ?) ? Is it a visual or headless flow ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke added test code. Don't see how start/stoptest makes a different here. limits are not my issue here. Flow is autolaunched. I don;'t have problems in my code apparently. It's a saleforce issue.

Comment: Because those test methods also force all asynchronous features to execute (and are a general best practice). Without diving into the documentation adding those would be my guess. Or calling the flow start() method excplicitly from the test.

Answer (score 2):

In your test method add below line.

```
System.assertEquals('expected value', controller.startflow());
```

Replace 'expected value' with your assumption and call your method as second parameter.

Comment: this does not solve the OP question -- once the flow is started, control never returns to the testmethod and hence the final lines in red aren't covered.

Answer (score 2):

Saariko - sorry for the delay; I needed to do a simple test

Here's a flow - all it does is post to Chatter and returns the ID of the post in flow variable named `PostId`

[image]

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class VisualFlowController {

    Flow.Interview.AutoLaunchedFlow_ReturnsId flow;

    public VisualFlowController() {
        this.flow = new Flow.Interview.AutoLaunchedFlow_ReturnsId(new map<String,Object>());
    }

    public void start() {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'Request autolaunch flow to start');
        this.flow.start();      // launch flow

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'after flow executes - chatter post Id = ' + 
                                        this.flow.getVariableValue('PostId'));
    }

}
```

**TestMethod**

```
@isTest
private with sharing class VisualFlowControllerTest {

    @isTest
    private static void testAutoLaunchedFlow() {
        Test.startTest();
            VisualFlowController ctlr = new VisualFlowController();
            ctlr.start();
        Test.stopTest();    
    }
}
```

Test method returns this debug output, indicating that flow executes in test method

```
Request autolaunch flow to start
after flow executes - chatter post Id = 0D54000003gC9uHCAS
```

and code coverage is 100%

[image]

If I remove the `Test.startTest() - stopTest()` - I still get 100% test coverage and the debug output is the same

```
Request autolaunch flow to start
after flow executes - chatter post Id = 0D54000003gCASTCA4
```

**All code at V36.0**

So

1. Test.startTest-stoptest doesn't matter - autolaunched flow should be synchronous as user interaction is not permitted
2. Previous comments of mine are bogus
3. Only thing I can think of for you is either a) check code version or b) verify in debug logs that flow isn't blowing up in the testmethod